# Is it okay to take off several weeks of work?

Tags: professionalism

I am fifteen and am going to be getting a job. My grandmother is getting older and I need to take off two weeks of work to see her and visit her. I think if I only took that time off it would be okay. But my boyfriend and I planned on spending a week with his family at the beach. Would it be bad to take off a week of work only a month later?

Comment: Do you have some kind of allowance? How does your job work? If you are 15 I'd guess you don't have a regular 40h/week "job" job.

Answer (score 4):

> Would it be bad to take off a week of work only a month later?

Depends on the type of job you have, the company policies and your locale's policies on minors. For instance, if you are a part-time hourly server, this likely isn't a big deal, because you don't have paid time off and the restaurant could just not schedule you for a shift during that time period.

It does look bad to take time off so close to starting. I think you have a good story with your grandmother, but the vacation with your boyfriend seems frivolous.

You could instead ask to start your new job after your trip with boyfriend.